# Are namespace collisions possible between function and parameter?

Tags: r

From a human / code serviceability perspective, it's sometimes desirable for a parameter to be given the same name as a function.

Here's a common example - a function that accepts a parameter called url (`url` is also a base R function)

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

my_func <- function(url) {
  read_html(url) %>% html_nodes('body') %>% html_text
}

my_func(url)
```

#### The question

Is there any reason to worry about functions and parameters of the same name?

An extremely simple way of asking the same thing; R lets me give a function and parameter the same name, but that doesn't mean I should. Is there any concrete reason(s) not to?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what issues this would cause, but if you call `url()` within your function, the original `url` function gets called, because R distinguishes between you just using the `url` variable and trying to call it.

Comment: @Marius I suspect the answer is therefore no. That there is never a case where there's ambiguity around whether `somename` is a function or a parameter, and therefore no reason to avoiding giving a function and parameter the same name?

Comment: user5783745: besides the answer I provided, here's a *soft* reason: readability and maintainability. Trying to troubleshoot a function when there are (say) variables names `a`, `b`, and `c` can produce confusion when seeing things like `c(1,c)`. While R might infer correctly (some/most of the time), my eyes are trained well to see `c` as a function. This comment is mostly about the *technique* of variable naming conventions, but (1) somebody else's code and (2) your code after 6 months of not using it ... both can rely heavily on quick visual understanding for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

There can be ambiguities:

```r
do.call(url, list(mtcars[1,], mtcars[1,]))
# Error in (function (description, open = "", blocking = TRUE, encoding = getOption("encoding"),  : 
#   invalid 'description' argument

url <- "rbind.data.frame"
do.call(url, list(mtcars[1,], mtcars[1,]))
#            mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4   21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX41  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
```

If R was perfectly smart enough to know that we meant the *function* named `url` and not the variable, then it would have erred again. While this is perhaps a contrived example, I don't think it's hard to imagine where a function is passed *uncalled* as an argument.

Comment: This example demonstrates a collision between a function and variable. But not a collision between a function and a parameter name? In the example, the parameter is still named `what` (i.e. `do.call(what, args, quote = FALSE, envir = parent.frame())`. Even though the argument is the object `url`

Comment: Once you are "inside" the function, a parameter name is just a variable (whether user-filled, default-value, or missing).

Comment: Said another way, a parameter name in a function definition is almost identical to a "regular" variable defined in every way (the only real difference is that `missing()` has meaning on a parameter but not on a locally-defined variable). What this means to me is that once inside the function, as far as naming convention and scope goes, a formal parameter and a variable defined in the function body are effectively identically handled, so the question about naming convention/conflict does not change.

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter is itself a function, you may run into issues:

```r
g <- function(f, ...) {
  f(1, ...)
}

f <- function(x) x + 1

g(`+`, 2)
#> [1] 3
g(2) # might expect this to error
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9000)</sup>